# Fastest way of reading txt files in C#

Tags: c#, regex, file-io

I'm working with a project and I'm a little bit confused. I've got from my teacher some txt files (from [his site](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/orlib/files/)  files: wt40.txt, wt50.txt, wt100.txt).

Every file structure looks similiar:

```
26    24    79    46    32    35    73    74    14    67    86    46    78    40    29    94    64    27    90    55
35    52    36    69    85    95    14    78    37    86    44    28    39    12    30    68    70     9    49    50
 1    10     9    10    10     4     3     2    10     3     7     3     1     3    10     4     7     7     4     7
 5     3     5     4     9     5     2     8    10     4     7     4     9     5     7     7     5    10     1     3
```

- Every number has 6 chars, but instead of leading zeros there are
  spaces
- At every line there are 20 numbers

File wt40.txt should be read as: first two lines to first List, next two lines to next List and third pair of lines to the third list. Next lines again should be put in pairs to those Lists.

In C++ I'm doing it in this simple way:

```
for(int ins=0; ins<125; ins++) //125 instances in file
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)  file>>tasks[i].p; //N elements at two first lines
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)  file>>tasks[i].w;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)  file>>tasks[i].d;
    tasks[i].putToLists();
}
```

But when I'm writing this in C# I have to open StreamReader, read every line, split it by regexp, cast them to int and add to lists. That's a lot of loops.
I cannot read every 6 chars and add them in three loops because those text files have messed up end of lines chars - sometimes it's just '\n' sometimes something more.

Isn't there any more simple way?

Comment: Investigate File.ReadAlLines and String.Split. Also, in a C# question we expect C# code (attempted solutions), not C++.

Comment: Also, post excerpts of your data files as part of the question.

Comment: A small detail relating to the semantics of the question - Reading is always the 'same' (tm) speed - it is out of your control. However, it is processing the data in line that slows a read down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is essentially a 20 by n table of 6 digit(character) numbers with leading spaces.

```
26    24    79    46    32    35    73    74    14    67    86    46    78    40    29    94    64    27    90    55
35    52    36    69    85    95    14    78    37    86    44    28    39    12    30    68    70     9    49    50
 1    10     9    10    10     4     3     2    10     3     7     3     1     3    10     4     7     7     4     7
 5     3     5     4     9     5     2     8    10     4     7     4     9     5     7     7     5    10     1     3
```

I don't understand the last sentence:

> File wt40.txt should be read as: first two lines to first List, next
>   two lines to next List and third pair of lines to the third list. Next
>   lines again should be put in pairs to those Lists.

Say you want to get the first 6 rows and create 3 lists each with 2 rows, you do could something like:

It is eager in that it reads everything into memory and then does its work.

```
const int maxNumberDigitLength = 6;
const int rowLengthInChars = maxNumberDigitLength * 20;
const int totalNumberOfCharsToRead = rowLengthInChars * maxNumberDigitLength;

char[] buffer = new char[totalNumberOfCharsToRead];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("wt40.txt")
{
    int numberOfCharsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, totalNumberOfCharsToRead);
}

// put them in your lists
IEnumerable<char> l1 = buffer.Take(rowLengthInChars);
IEnumerable<char> l2 = buffer.Skip(rowLengthInChars).Take(rowLengthInChars);
IEnumerable<char> l3 = buffer.Skip(rowLengthInChars*2).Take(rowLengthInChars);

// Get the list of strings from the list of chars using non LINQ method.
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(char c in l1)
{
    if(i < maxNumberDigitLength)
    {
        sb.Append(c);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    list1.Add(sb.ToString());
}

// LINQ method
string s = string.Concat(l1);
List<string> list1 = Enumerable
                   .Range(0, s.Length / maxNumberDigitLength)
                   .Select(i => s.Substring(i * maxNumberDigitLength, maxNumberDigitLength))
                   .ToList();     

// Parse to ints using LINQ projection
List<int> numbers1 = list1.Select(int.Parse);
List<int> numbers2 = list2.Select(int.Parse);
List<int> numbers3 = list3.Select(int.Parse);
```

Comment: Why do you call `ToList()` on buffer?

Comment: Why do you call it so often? :)

Comment: @SamLeach, `Array` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use LINQ methods directly against arrays. But the result of calling LINQ methods will be an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can't assign it to `List<T>`.

Comment: You're right. I thought not. Anyway, he wants a list, so I'll leave it.

Comment: @SamLeach You understood good what I have to do - just read them and save in lists. Your code looks great, but i'm trying to understand what this "lambda expression" does, can you get me a hint?
Edit: Oh it's gone :D I'm trying today to understand what is the meaning of "=>"

Comment: It's short for `x => int.Parse(x)`. Look up 'list projection linq'.

Comment: Thank you for help, I made this in 12 loops and it was definitely wrong so I had to find a better solution.

Comment: Everything would be good, but LinQ Projection to int wants IENumerable again, not Lists. What then?

Comment: If you have a list and need an enumerable use AsEnumerable(), if you have an enumerable and need a list use ToList().

Comment: Yes and always VS2013 says that after ToList() "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'. "

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there any more simple way?

Don't know if it's simpler but there is only one loop and a bit of `LINQ`:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("wt40.txt"))
{
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        List<int> currentList =
            Regex.Split(line, "\\s")
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
        if (currentList.Count > 0) // skip empty lines
        {
            if (count % 2 == 0) // append each second list to the previous one
            {
                lists.Add(currentList);
            }
            else
            {
                lists[count / 2].AddRange(currentList);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

In total you end up with 375 lists each containing 40 numbers (at least for `wt40.txt` input).